# Panchamundi and Navamundi asanas

Tags: tantra, shaktism, sadhana, asana, chinnamasta

I was curious about the Panchamundi and Navamundi asanas.

Is the provision of sitting and meditating in those asanas given in tantras of Sri Vidya, Kubjika Tantra or tantras like Jayadrathayamala?

Does the Chinnamasta Sadhana have the use of meditating, while sitting in the Panchamundi asana?

Panchamundi asana seems to be present mostly only in the Bengal and I never heard of it outside the Bengali paramparas,
not much even in the Assam!!!

Would be very grateful if someone could answer this query of mine.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, I hope anyone here doesn't attaches wrong notions with skull and defame Shaktas and the upasanas. Because, to western community skull or bones are deemed as impure or something horrific & **Shamanic**, lol.
Why skull is used is altogether a different & esoteric topic. Which I shall avoid.

[image]

As Bhagwati herself in form of Chandi sits on skulls, thus her presence is very much experienced on Mundasana. Thus only highest of sadhaka approach this.

```
Is the provision of sitting and meditating in those asanas given in tantras of Sri Vidya, Kubjika Tantra or tantras like Jayadrathayamala?
```

Yes, the Mundasaan (skull seat) appears in various tantras and are mentioned to accomplish various tantric sadhanas.

Devi Saptakotishwari Kalpa is present in 3rd & 4th Patala of Jayadrathayamal.
In Kashmiri Shaktism Saptakoteshwari devi is one of the 4 Pratyangiras.
She is depicted sitting on **Saptamundasana**,

> ……. कवलननिरता **सप्तमुण्डासनस्था** प्रोद्भोताधार चक्रात्प्रलयशिखि शिखा……….

Shrijayadrathayamala exclusively states this,

> ……………………………………………..।
> **सप्तमुण्डासनरतां** तत्सङ्ख्या भुवनाध्वगाम् ॥

Devi Shwet Kali too sits upon panchamundi asan.

Other than that some other referances are,

In Mundamala Tantra,

> शवस्योपरि मुंडे वा जले वा कंठपूरिते ।
> On corpse, Skull or water till neck.

In Yogini tantra,

> मुंडे वाsयोनिके देवि त्वचि व्याघ्रस्य वा प्रिये।
> Oh beloved one, on Skull, or Yoni or on the skin of Tiger.

Yogini tantra further explains Trimundasaan & Panchamundasana as,

> नरमहिषमांर्जारमुंडकानि वरानने।
> अथवा परमेशानि नृमुंडत्रयमादरात्।।
> Oh, Varanane! Gather human skull, buffalo skull, the skull of cat or three human skulls.

> शिवासर्पसारमेयवृषभानां महेश्वरी।
> नरमुण्डं तथा मध्ये पंचमुण्डी समीरिता।।
> The skulls of Shiva(Jackal), Snake, Dog, Bull & Human. Oh Maheshwari, this are the panchmunda.

> अथवा परमेशानी नराणाम् पंच मुण्डकान्।
> तथा शतं साहस्त्रम् वायुतं लक्षम् तथैव च।।
> Or else Parmeshani, five human skulls are accepted as panchmunda. And hundered, thousand, lakh are considered too.

Thus the number varies from 1,3,5,7,9,100,1k to crore (Kotimundasan).

Navamundasana is mentioned by Mahamahopadhyay Gopinath Kaviraj in a book called Vishuddhabani. If you want to know more about Navamundasana, kindly read the book.

```
Does the Chinnamasta Sadhana have the use of meditating, while sitting in the Panchamundi asana?
```

Not just Chinnamasta, on Mundasana the mantra to any Mahavidya or Anga, Upangavidya can be chanted as said by Srī Guru.
Eg, Ramakrishna Paramhamsa chanted Kali mantra on Panchmundi when he was given diksha in Tantra by Bhairabi debi.
Bamakhepa chanted Tara mantra on panchmundi asan as said by Kailashpati Baba.
Some other sadhakas who did tantra sadhana on Mundasana are Kamalakantha, Kailashpati Baba himself, Mahamahopadhyay Gopinath Kaviraj, Bhairabi devi, Sadhaka Ramaprasad, Maharaja Rameshwarsingh Thakur & many more such accomplished follow the list.

```
I never heard of it outside the Bengali paramparas, not much even in the Assam!!!
```

Mundasanas are prevalent over whole India. And tirths like Kashi, Kamapura & Vindhyanchal are flooded with those. It's just that in Bengal, Shaktism is highly prevelant thus you find such temples publicly. Or else, mundasanas are never disclosed by sadhakas.

Few, other temples outside Bengal, where the deity is stationed over mundasana.

Kali Bari in Kaiserbagh, Lukhnow

Kali mandir, Darbanga, Patna

Rankini Devi temple, Jadugora, Singhbhum, Jharkhand.

Comment: Thank you so much.....but another of my query is that whether the panchamunda asanas are present in tantras of kashmiri origin like that of jayadrathayamala, trika or evwn kubjika mata and texts of sri vidya?.....because i read somewhere that practice of siddhilakshmi also requires panchamunda asana......but here in Nepal even though siddhilakshmi is worshipped secretly we dont find any mundasanas here......neither do we find mundasanas in Tibet where vajrayana practices are prevalent everywhere though i heard tgat buddhiat yogini tantras also mention use of mundasanas.

Comment: @samiqueupreti so srry, tbh actually I haven't read about Kashmir Shaivism or Trika much, so I don't find it right to quote without complete knowledge. & Siddhalaxmi indeed is worshipped upon mundasana. As, I said sadhakas nvr reveal mundasana to other sadhakas, untill their guru says so, thus you don't know abt them. Now, to say Buddha himself taught Vashishta muni to use mundasana and then he got siddhi of Tara devi, thus Buddhism has it too. Anyways, regarding this if you have doubt kindly Dm to, 'ishaivite' page on insta. He is accomplished Kashmiri Shaiv. Maybe he can help you wid this.

Comment: Thank u so much!!!

Comment: @samiqueupreti I found referance for Satpamundi asan in Jayadrathayamala. I have updated it here too, kindly check the answer once again. If in future, I found any references from Kubjikamata or Shrividya will update it here.

Comment: Thank u so much....i'm very grateful for ur guidance